# Elasticsearch issue types removal

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run the below code in Python using Elasticsearch Ver 7.1, however the following errors come up:

```
ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning: [types removal] Using include_type_name in put mapping requests is deprecated. The parameter will be removed in the next major version.
  client.indices.put_mapping(index=indexName,doc_type='diseases', body=diseaseMapping, include_type_name=True)
```

followed by:

```
ElasticsearchDeprecationWarning: [types removal] Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated, use the typeless endpoints instead (/{index}/_doc/{id}, /{index}/_doc, or /{index}/_create/{id}).
  client.index(index=indexName,doc_type=docType, body={"name": disease,"title":currentPage.title,"fulltext":currentPage.content})
```

How I am supposed to amend my code to make it ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTKaH.png)) work in line with Elasticsearch 7X version? Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the code is just throwing a warning rather than an error. It just means that a feature the library you are using will soon be removed from Elasticsearch. Using the version of the Elasticsearch python library that matches the version of ES you are using should fix the issue.

Comment: Many thanks for a quick reply. If it is not an error, I will leave it as it is then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a warning right now, but it will become an error in Elasticsearch 8.

From last few version, Elasticsearch has been planning the removal of index types inside an index

1. ES5 - Setting index.mapping.single_type: true on an index will enable the single-type-per-index behavior which will be enforced in 6.0.
2. In ES6 - you can't have more than 1 index type inside 1 index
3. In ES7 - the concept of types inside an index has been deprecated
4. In ES8 - it will be removed, and you can't use types for query or while inserting documents

My suggestion would be to design an application and mapping in such a way that it doesn't include type parameter in index

To know the reason why elastic search has done this here is a link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed

Answer (score 1):

A common issue (**and difficult to spot**) for this error message could be misspelling the endpoint, e.g.:

**Misspelled:**

/search

**Correct:**

/_search

Double check if your endpoint is correct as ElasticSearch may think you are trying to manipulate (add, update, remove) a document and you are giving a type, which is not the case (you are trying to call an endpoint).